# PowerShell case sensitive find Property Name

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I try to find a way to Select a property by the name which should be case sensitive.
i found a question here where the problem can be solved with this:
{$_ -match "(?-i)^SMTP"}
This however doesnt return any data.
If I try to fix it, like say to filter with PSObject.Properties.Name I get the whole PSObject table.

Here is my code for reference:

```
[...]
$ProxyAddresses = [pscustomobject]@{}
$ProxyAddresses = $Table | Select sip:*,smtp:*,notes:*
$ProxyAddresses = $ProxyAddresses.PSObject.Properties.Name.Where{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ProxyAddresses.$_)} | Sort-Object
if ([bool](Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $($ObjmbxUser.EmailAddresses | Select ProxyAddressString -ExpandProperty ProxyAddressString) -DifferenceObject $ProxyAddresses)) {
**$NewPrimary = $Aliases |? {$_.PSObject.Properties.Name -match "(?-i)^SMTP"}**
[...]
```

The $Table contains a HTML Request which includes mail addresses with value name starting with SIP, Notes or SMTP/smtp.
I try now to save the SMTP apart from the table and remove it then from the table.
So I can use it afterwards.

I expect that i can filter my PSCustomObject with the Select-Object or Where-Object statement but it isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself after reviewing the whole code with the following code:

```
[String]$NewPrimary = ""
$NewPrimary = $($Aliases.PSObject.Properties -cmatch "SMTP").Value
$NewPrimary = $NewPrimary.Split(":",2)[1]
```

This way you get all Properties with cmatch SMTP case sensitive.